# Does Apache Parquet support Custom Filter Predicate on Repeated values?

Tags: parquet, parquet-mr

Does Apache Parquet support Custom Filter Predicate on Repeated values? By applying a filter on a repeated value, I get:

> FilterPredicates do not currently support repeated columns. Column
> part.x is repeated

The filter I set on the x double repeated value is:

```
FilterApi.gtEq(FilterApi.doubleColumn("part.x"), 4d)
```

Is there any way to form a custom filter to apply on the repeated value?

Comment: I was curious about this as well, it looks like it's not currently supported. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-34